# Eevee render lights cast own shadow

Tags: rendering, shadows, eevee-render-engine

I am using Eevee rendering. I have installed Blender 2.8 (tried 2 different versions on each) on 2 different machines. They both have the same problem. All light sources cast their own shadow. The default scene shows like this. No changes were made to the scene, and I don't think I changed any of the preference options. [image: Default Scene]

When I add a plane you can see what is happening.

[image: Light Shadow]
You can see the shadow circle around the object. 
If I turn off shadows on the light, everything looks normal, except for the fact that nothing casts a shadow. You can see that it does create a little light when it's right next to something.
The shadow grows/shrinks when I adjust the shadow distance parameters. 
I'm new to blender, so I'm not sure what information would be helpful, but so far I can't find anything to fix this, and no one else seems to have this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blender 2.8 is still in development and hasn’t been released yet. If you think you’ve found a bug you should report it to the developers. Information about bug reporting can be found here: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports

Comment: No, developers are aware it is not complete, bug reports are only open for reproducible crashes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug on unreleased experimental development software

Comment: I understand it's experimental, but it doesn't mean people couldn't help me if they know what is going on. I just can't find help anywhere. I have a class that uses this version, yet no one else is having this issue, and no one there seems to be able to help. So I tried here.